# Why would I receive a blank email if a plus is in the email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, sendmail, sendgrid

In my Rails app, we send out emails to users and some are coming through blank.  So far, it seems that it only happens when the recipient email has a plus (+) in it (some+address@domain.com).  When I test locally using sendmail, the email will not even go out if there is a plus.  In production, using SMTP through SendGrid, the email comes through but it is blank.  Is that expected behavior?  Any way around it?

Comment: any use? http://notfaq.wordpress.com/2006/07/20/plus-sign-in-email-addresses/

Comment: Turns out it was a bug in my code.  All fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

An email sent to some+address@somain.com should go to some@domain.com, since the + sign separates real addresses from internally-rerouted ones.

Plus, minus and the exclamation point traditionally have special meanings for more explicit handling of emails once they are delivered by the normal email service.